# Constructible points from $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, geometric-construction

I have recently learned the proof for why you cannot "double" the cube, trisect the angle, and "square" the circle. I understand the whole analysis, assuming that a point is constructible if it is from $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$. However, I am wondering, why do we assume that a point is constructable only if it is from $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$.

My book give the definition that "We call a point in the plane constructable if it is constructable from $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$, that is, from the set of all points in the plane with rational coefficients".

This definition seems to make sense. However, what guarantees that this is the case? I understand that the proof would not work if we considered a point being constructible from $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$, but why not $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$?
What about a straight edge and compass?

Comment: This is false, point $(\sqrt{2},0)$ is constructible (easy to check) but not in $\Bbb Q\times\Bbb Q$.

Comment: @Wojowu Sorry, I should have been more specific. I do not mean that $(\sqrt{2},0)$ is not constructable. I am wondering why we start with $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: If you look at some actual constructions of things, they all start with a single length being given (may as well call that length $1$) and go from there using compass and ruler only. Getting to QxQ is relatively easy. Then to other points step by step. One cannot just pop in random real points during the construction, they have to come from previously constructed points using ruler, compass.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean with "start with". In standard setting, as far as I know, we start with just two points one unit apart.

Comment: After your edit the question makes no sense, because you say P is constructible if it's in a set containing constructible points.

Comment: By "start with"  a single length, means the same as two points a unit apart. [I should have specified the starting length is definitely 1, in order to have well-defined set of constructible points]

Comment: @coffeemath thanks! That makes more sense.

Comment: @wojowu It wasn't my edit. I so far don't see the idea of your objection to my particular comment... no problem that I don't see it ...

Comment: In algebra, one studies *fields* of constructible numbers, and the base field is $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Is there a link you have for a topic on constructable numbers that would be useful?

Comment: Searching, once you have enough search terms, should be effective. I like the book by George Martin, *Geometric Constructions*, but do not know the level at which you are working, or what information you seek.

Comment: If we can't get there from $\mathbb Q \times \mathbb Q$ you certainly can't get there from two points unit distance apart. In fact it is not difficult to construct any given point with rational co-ordinates, though it is impossible to construct all such points in finite time. By starting here you make sure you have "all the ones you might need" - knowing that any construction will only use finitely many. If you had all the real points you wouldn't need to construct them.